# How to agregate/group php array by SQL timedate/unix timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, grouping

How to count/group data from array into hours from MySQL timedate format or unix timestamp?

My array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => id
                [1] => name 
                [2] => 2013-01-10 00:36:00 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
                [0] => id
                [1] => name 
                [2] => 2013-01-10 00:36:00 
    ) 
)
```

How to shrink thousands of items like this and agregate them somehow to hours or even days? I just need rough number of rows with given hour in specyfic day.

Comment: Use Group By in your SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try SELECT * from table GROUP BY HOUR(date_column) WHERE condition...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Comment: GROUB BY should follow WHERE, not SELECT ;-)

Comment: OK I need GROUP BY DAY, not HOUR, but how to GROUP BY DAY, and inside BY HOUR?

Answer (score 1):

Valid code for my case from answer from @Robert Seddon-Smith:

SELECT `id`, `name`, `day`, `key` 
FROM table
WHERE day > '2013 6-01 00:00:00' && day < '2013-6-31 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY YEAR(day), MONTH(day), DAY(day), HOUR(day), SECOND(day)

Comment: Good on you for posting a final solution